# Close Cookies Popup with RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to scrape a real estate website, but the first time I open the url I get the accept cookies popup. I haven't been able to close it.

```
url_search <- "https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/myytavat-asunnot?pagination=1&locations=%5B%5B64,6,%22Helsinki%22%5D%5D&cardType=100&price%5Bmax%5D=350000&size%5Bmin%5D=25&buildingType%5B%5D=1&buildingType%5B%5D=256"

driver <- rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"), chromever="104.0.5112.79")
rd <- driver[["client"]]
rd$navigate(url_search)
```

I have tried accessing the button:

```
rd$findElement(using = "class",
               "message-component message-button no-children focusable buttons-row sp_choice_type_11 last-focusable-el")
```

But I get an `Summary: InvalidSelector` error

I have also tried switching to the frame and navigating my way to the button, but haven't managed to do it.

```
iframe = rd$findElement(using = "tag name", "iframe")
rd$switchToFrame(iframe)
rd$findElement(using = "class", value = "message-component message-button no-children focusable buttons-row sp_choice_type_11 last-focusable-el")
```

Any help or idea?

Comment: Somehow I don't face the _get the accept cookies popup_. Can you update the question with the relevant text based HTML.

Comment: Transcribed for H3reux: I got the same things one time and i just click the button accept, you should try using XPATH element_locator : `rd$findElement(using = "XPATH", "The XPATH").click`.